# Default records in Room database when creating a database in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I want to create a diet app in which will be in multiple languages. The products will be stored in the Room database. I thought I would retrieve the product names from different string-array from value/string depending on the region, and then create records in the product_table. I've tried several ways to do this, but none of them perform. Perhaps I am approaching the problem wrong and the approach needs to be changed. The database works because I can see the tables in App Inspection and I can enter records. I am using Depencency Injection in this project. What is the best way to do this? I have uploaded my code below:

```
@Entity(tableName = DATABASE_TABLE_PRODUCT)
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val productId: Int = 0,
    val name: String,
    val categoryId: Int,
    val description: String,
    val isAllergen: Boolean = false
)
```

```
@Dao
interface ProductDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table")
    fun getAllProducts(): Flow<List<Product>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE categoryId=:category")
    fun getProductCategory(category: String): Flow<List<Product>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE productId=:productId")
    fun getSelectedProduct(productId: Int): Flow<Product>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE isAllergen = :isAllergenValue")
    fun getAllergens(isAllergenValue: Boolean = true): Flow<List<Product>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addProduct(product: Product)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateProduct(product: Product)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteProduct(product: Product)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE name LIKE '%' || :searchQuery || '%'")
    fun searchProductByName(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<Product>>
}
```

```
@ViewModelScoped
class ProductRepository @Inject constructor(private val productDao: ProductDao) {
    val getAllProducts: Flow<List<Product>> = productDao.getAllProducts()
    val getAllergenProducts: Flow<List<Product>> = productDao.getAllergens(true)

    suspend fun addProduct(product: Product) {
        productDao.addProduct(product = product)
    }

    suspend fun deleteProduct(product: Product) {
        productDao.deleteProduct(product = product)
    }

    suspend fun updateProduct(product: Product) {
        productDao.updateProduct(product = product)
    }

    fun getProductCategory(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<Product>> {
        return productDao.getProductCategory(category = searchQuery)
    }

    fun getSelectedProduct(productId: Int): Flow<Product> {
        return productDao.getSelectedProduct(productId = productId)
    }

    fun searchByProductName(searchQuery: String): Flow<List<Product>> {
        return productDao.searchProductByName(searchQuery = searchQuery)
    }

}
```

```
@Database(entities = [Product::class, Diary::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class DietDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModul {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        DietDatabase::class.java,
        DATABASE_NAME
    ).build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideProductDao(database: DietDatabase) = database.productDao()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDiaryDao(database: DietDatabase) = database.diaryDao()
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository
) : ViewModel() {


    // getting all products using RequestState
    private val _allProducts = MutableStateFlow<RequestState<List<Product>>>(RequestState.Idle)
    val allProducts: StateFlow<RequestState<List<Product>>> = _allProducts


    fun getAllProducts() {
        _allProducts.value = RequestState.Loading
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                productRepository.getAllProducts.collect {
                    _allProducts.value = RequestState.Success(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _allProducts.value = RequestState.Error(e)
        }
    }

    private val _selectedProduct: MutableStateFlow<Product?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val selectedProduct: StateFlow<Product?> = _selectedProduct

    fun getSelectedProduct(productId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            productRepository.getSelectedProduct(productId).collect { product ->
                _selectedProduct.value = product
            }
        }
    }

    fun addProduct(product: Product){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            productRepository.addProduct(product)
        }
    }

}
```

```
<string-array name="vegetables">
    <item>Asparagus</item>
    <item>Aubergine</item>
    <item>Beet</item>
    <item>Botquin</item>
    <item>Brussel sprouts</item>
    <item>Broccoli</item>
    <item>Cabbage (Red)</item>
    <item>Cabbage (White)</item>
    <item>Carole</item>
    <item>Carrot</item>
    <item>Cauliflower</item>
    <item>Chives</item>
    <item>Cinnamon</item>
    <item>Cocktail tomato</item>
    <item>Cucumber</item>
    <item>Cucumber</item>
    <item>Dill</item>
    <item>Kale</item>
    <item>Leek</item>
    <item>Onion</item>
    <item>Paprika</item>
    <item>Parsley root</item>
    <item>Potato</item>
    <item>Pumpkin</item>
    <item>Rabarb</item>
    <item>Radish</item>
    <item>Salad</item>
    <item>Selery root</item>
    <item>Selery root</item>
    <item>Spinach</item>
    <item>Tomato</item>
</string-array>
```

[App Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmdLQ.png)

I,ve tried this solution (this below is template):

```
@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    // Define your DAO interfaces here

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "app_database"
                )
                .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        // Populate the database with initial data
                        // For example:
                        val userDao = INSTANCE?.userDao()
                        userDao?.insert(User("John Doe"))
                        userDao?.insert(User("Jane Smith"))
                    }
                })
                .build().also { INSTANCE = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't use the context in a straightforward way, because Local.current, used in:

```
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val vegetables = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.vegetables)
```

needs to be used in the @Composable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. I changed:

```
 @HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository
) : ViewModel() {
```

to

```
 @HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository,
, private val application: Application )
) : AndroidViewModel(application)() {
```

And this is how I got the contex without @Composable.

Next I added:

```
    // initial products
    private var isAllProductsInitialized = false

    init {
        getAllProducts()
    }

    fun getAllProducts() {
        _allProducts.value = RequestState.Loading
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                productRepository.getAllProducts.collect {
                    _allProducts.value = RequestState.Success(it)
                    if (!it.isEmpty() && isAllProductsInitialized == false)
                        isAllProductsInitialized = true
                    if (it.isEmpty() && isAllProductsInitialized == false) {
                        initProducts()
                        isAllProductsInitialized = true
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _allProducts.value = RequestState.Error(e)
        }
    }

     fun addProduct(product: Product) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            productRepository.addProduct(product)
        }
    }

    fun initProducts() {
        // product list
        val vegetables = application.resources.getStringArray(R.array.vegetables)
        for (i in vegetables)
            addProduct(Product(name = i, categoryId = 1, isAllergen = false, description = ""))


    }
```